# Laravel - retrieve only relationships that exist and match conditions

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, relationship

In Laravel I want to retrieve all clients that have a relationship and where the relationship matches some given parameters. At the moment the bellow snipped returns clients that match the relationship criteria, and also clients with empty relationships. Any idea how I can get only clients that match the relationship criteria? Thanks

```
$constraint = function($query){
    $query->where('type', 'Sales')->where('fdate', '!=', '0000-00-00')->where('archive', 'n')->orderBy('fdate', 'asc')->limit(1);
};
$brands = Client::select('ccid')->whereHas('history', $constraint)->with(['history' => $constraint])->limit(10)->get();

return $brands;
```

Here is a snipped of the returned results. Client's with empty `history` should not be returned.

```
{
    "ccid": 31753,
    "history": []
},    
{
    "ccid": 32061,
    "history": [
        {
        "hid": 415471,
        "ccid": 32061,
        "uid": 18097,
        "hdate": "2019-09-19",
        "fdate": "2020-01-14",
        "type": "Sales",
        "archive": "n",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "ccid": 32194,
    "history": []
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
$brands = Client::select('ccid')->whereHas('history', 
    function($query) {
        $query->where('type', 'Sales')
            ->where('fdate', '!=', '0000-00-00')
            ->where('archive', 'n')->orderBy('fdate', 'asc')
        ->limit(1);
    })->with('history')->limit(10)->get();
```

Based on your code it returns clients with no relationship, also it might be because of the `->with()` in your query.

Comment: This only returns the client's property **ccid** and no relationship. Removing the `select` this returns the clients but with no relationship.

Comment: I updated my answer. Just remove the criteria in your with.

Comment: This returns all the relationships for a `client`  and these are not filtered by any of the criteria: sales, fdate, archive etc

Comment: why it will not, because it will return clients having a history where history type is equal to 'Sales' and where history fdate is not equal to '0000-00-00' and history archive is equal to 'n'.

Comment: not sure why, but for example for the client: 32061 I get returned all of the relationships not just the ones matching the criteria.

Comment: What d you mean of return all relationship ? But the clients are correct ? just the history relationship ?

Comment: It will just return maybe because all of that clients passed the criteria, it's impossible if not.

Comment: Yes, I think all of the clients that matched the criteria, but why all of the relationships for each client, instead of the specific relationship?

Comment: Maybe because that relationship is appended in your client model that's why every time client model is called then that relationship will also be called.

Comment: This is my Client model: `public function history() { return $this->hasMany('App\Models\History', 'ccid');}` and my history model: `public function history(){ return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Client', 'ccid'); }`